# Как сделать редирект в конфиге Apache или htaccess используя правило от nginx?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, yii2, .htaccess, apache

Есть страницы с такими старыми URL`ами.

```
site.com/customer/index.php?product=12
```

Так как имя клиента(**customer**) динамическое и на новом проекте такой папки нет, хочу передать это имя как параметер вместе с остальными данными, чтобы на запрос апачь проверил если папка не существует, то переделать запрос и указать эту папку в качестве аргумента `oldUrl`:

```
site.com/?oldUrl=customer&product=12
```

В nginx конфиге есть вот такое правило:

```
try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?oldUrl=$uri&$args;
```

Как перенаправить 301 редиректом страницы в apache?
Спасибо.

**Обновление:**
Вот мой root .htaccess файл:

```
    Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/manager/$
RewriteRule ^(manager)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/manager
RewriteRule ^manager(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} ^/([a-z0-9]+)/index\.php?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.+ /index.php?oldUrl=%1&%2 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^oldUrl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

**Обновление.**

После применения правил предложенных @uberchel УРЛ формируется правильно. 
`http://site.local/index.php?oldUrl=tonytest&product=2&category=23&f=3&n=3&m=2`

Только апачь стал ругаться

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Привожу `htaccess` из `frontend/web/` директории:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Что может мешать отрендерить файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю это решение вам нужно ?
У вас ошибка была, так как вы после всем манипуляций, опять шло перенапровление последним правилом, поэтому для корректной работы пришлось навешать больше условий.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/manager/$
RewriteRule ^(manager)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/manager
RewriteRule ^manager(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} ^/([a-z0-9]+)/index\.php?(.+)?
RewriteRule ^.+ /?oldUrl=%1&%2 [R=302,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^oldUrl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

Comment: Т.е если у меня может быть некоторое колличество аргументов в старом УРЛе, то финальная версия выглядет примерно так?: `%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} ^/([a-z0-9]+)/index.php?$` и последняя строка: `^(.*) http://apache.loc/?oldUrl=%1&%2 [R=302,NC]`. Мне необходимо динамически перекидывать все аргументы в конец УРЛа.

Comment: Тогда используйте так: %{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} ^/([a-z0-9]+)/index.php?(.+)$

Comment: Спасибо, дайте мне время проверить, если можете исправьте ваш ответ.

Comment: я обновил вопрос с логами апача, помогите пжл понять что я делаю не так. Мне кажется ваше решение верное, может я не там его записываю. Спасибо

Comment: я обновил вопрос с комментариями, используя ваш код, у меня ошибки появились. Апачь ругается, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Целый день юзал не работает как надо, УРЛ образуется как надо, спасибо но вот апачь выдает мне `Object not found!`. обновил свой вопрос с `htaccess` из `web` директории. Спасибо что помогаете мне.

Comment: Немного изменил ваш код, но в целом он правельный. Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customer/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://site.com/?oldUrl=customer&product=%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Если параметр product встречается только для customer, то первое правило можно убрать:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://site.com/?oldUrl=customer&product=%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: `customer` у меня может быть любое имя и цифры. Пример `alex123`. На старом проекте существует такая папка с индексным файлом внутри. На новом, необходимо передать название этой папки как параметер. Если я не точно выразился или остались вопросы напишите. Спасибо